# How can I convert an array of strings to an object using jq?

Tags: arrays, json, shell, object, jq

If I have an array such as this one:

```
[
  [
    "AppA",
    "ServiceA",
    "SecretKey",
    "topSecretKeyA"
  ],
  [
    "AppB",
    "ServiceB",
    "SecretKey",
    "topSecretKeyB"
  ],
  [
    "AppC",
    "ServiceC",
    "SecretKey",
    "topSecretKeyC"
  ]
]
```

How can I convert this to an object that looks like the following?

```
{
  "AppA": {
    "ServiceA": {
      "SecretKey": "topSecretKeyA"
    }
  },
  "AppB": {
    "ServiceB": {
      "SecretKey": "topSecretKeyB"
    }
  },
  "AppC": {
    "ServiceC": {
      "SecretKey": "topSecretKeyC"
    }
  }
}
```

I think I need to use reduce but I can't quite figure out how to do it. I have tried a number of variations of this:

`jq 'reduce .[] as $k (null; {($k: .})'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setpath` ([manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#setpath%28PATHS%3BVALUE%29)) to set a given path to a value:

```bash
reduce .[] as $k (null; setpath($k[:-1]; $k[-1]))
```

```json
{
  "AppA": {
    "ServiceA": {
      "SecretKey": "topSecretKeyA"
    }
  },
  "AppB": {
    "ServiceB": {
      "SecretKey": "topSecretKeyB"
    }
  },
  "AppC": {
    "ServiceC": {
      "SecretKey": "topSecretKeyC"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with `map` and `from_entries`

```
map({key: .[0], value: {(.[1]): {(.[2]): .[3]}}}) | from_entries
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for this specific scenario but I actually wanted the solution to work for variable length arrays. I forgot to mention that!